# Does addition of SSL layer increase the Response time?

Tags: ssl, load-testing

1. Does the response time increase for a page with with SLL layer compared to the same page without SSL layer?
2. If Yes, is that the reason that a SSL layer Encryption is added to it? Anything else which I have missed?
3. Simply for the Home page, without being logged into the application, do we need to have SSL layer to our page?

Better to understand: Why we do not have SSL layer for http://www.facebook.com.

If FB is right then why we have SSL layer for home page for www.gmail.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course.
2. Encryption plus the handshake plus possible space overheads.
3. No, but if there is a login form in the page it is customary, so as to provide a visual assurance that the password will be encrypted.
4. 'We' don't have SSL for gmail.com. Gmail does. If you want to know why their site is built the way it is, ask them.

Comment: possible space overheads : How ? Can you please provide me a brief idea or a related link will do. Thanks

Comment: @chinmaybrahma SSL sends data in records that have extra metadata in them such as type, length, version, and a MAC. If you write single bytes for example there can be a data explosion of 44x.